# Similitud de arraylist en c# a visual basic?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Estaba probando un código en aspx.cs que lo tomé de un video en youtube, en el se crea una lista multidimensional y se muestra en un gridview en una página , voy a poner el código:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <asp:GridView ID="TablaDimensionTres" runat="server" Caption="Tres Dimensiones" Width="450px"></asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TablaMultiple();
        }
    }

    private void TablaMultiple()
    {
       string[,] lista =
        {
            {"S", "Miranda", "Calle 2 ", "7895623" },
            {"G", "Fuentes", "Calle 3", "124578" },
            {"C", "Uribe", "Luis 11", "12564523" }
        };



        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Nombre");
        dt.Columns.Add("Apellido");
        dt.Columns.Add("Direccion");
        dt.Columns.Add("Rut");

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows[i]["Nombre"] = lista[i, 0].ToString();
            dt.Rows[i]["Apellido"] = lista[i, 1].ToString();
            dt.Rows[i]["Direccion"] = lista[i, 2].ToString();
            dt.Rows[i]["Rut"] = lista[i, 3].ToString();

            TablaDimensionTres.DataSource = dt;
            TablaDimensionTres.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Mi consulta es, existe algo u alternativa a este código para hacer una tabla  pero con asp.vb?? He estado buscando en internet pero no encuentro mucho, la lógica la entiendo bien pero nunca he programado en visual basic y menos para hacer una página web.

Mi idea es poder generar algo similar y yo por medio del código poder agregar o eliminar items.

En C# yo se que si ya tengo mi lista puedo poner por ejemplo **lista.add()** y le voy cargando items, pero desconozco para visual basic.

Si me pueden orientar se los agradecería.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Es exactamente igual.. la documentacion de uno te dice como se escribe lo mismo en el otro... https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es lo mismo podes crear una clase  con un constructos y con los metodos get y set para llenar la lista

```
Public Class Personas
Private _nombre As String
Private _apellido As String
Private _edad As Integer

'propiedades
Public Property Nombre() As String
    Get
        Return _nombre
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _nombre = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Apellido() As String
    Get
        Return _apellido
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _apellido = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Edad() As Integer
    Get
        Return _edad
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _edad = value
    End Set
End Property
'constructor
Public Sub New(ByVal nombre As String, ByVal apellido As String, ByVal edad As Integer)
    _nombre = nombre
    _apellido = apellido
    _edad = edad
End Sub
'registros
Public Shared Function Registros() As List(Of Personas)
    Dim personas As New List(Of Personas)()

    personas.Add(New Personas("Cristian", "Torres", 20))
    personas.Add(New Personas("Jose", "Alfaro", 18))
    personas.Add(New Personas("Briseyda", "Flores", 12))
    personas.Add(New Personas("Diana", "Turcios", 17))
    personas.Add(New Personas("Miguel", "Fernadez", 40))
    personas.Add(New Personas("Pedro", "Perez", 11))
    personas.Add(New Personas("Nicole", "Garcia", 20))

    Return personas
End Function
```

End Class

y la implemtas

```
GridView1.DataSource = Personas.Registros()
```

Aquí te explico es con datagridview pero seria lo mismo para un gridview
[Obtener Datos Filtrados Usando Linq](http://cristiantorresalfaro.blogspot.com/2012/06/obtener-datos-filtrados-usando-linq.html)